# how do I configure my database server to accept remote connections outside ide?

Tags: derby

I made a Derby server application in java that basically just launches a gui from which I can start, stop, see properties, see runtime info, etc.; using a NetworkServerControl.class.

I run the server application from withing Netbeans IDE and it acceps local and remote connections.

I generated jar files to run it outside of Netbeans, and it works fine "locally", but does not accept remote connections.

I'm using Windows 10, and can't find which properties or permissions I must configure in order to accept remote connections. The same application under Netbeans does the work.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
This is how I create de Server instance:

```
public Server(String derbyHome, InetAddress address, int port) throws Exception {
    if (derbyHome == null || address == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid parameters");
    }
    System.setProperty(DERBY_HOME_PROPERTY, derbyHome);
    control = new NetworkServerControl(address, port, ADMIN, AMIN_PWD);
    this.derbyHome = derbyHome;
    this.address   = address;
    this.port      = port;
}

public void start() throws Exception {
    control.start();
}
```

Comment: Which configuration of Derby are you using: Client/Server or Embedded? See http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/getstart/cgsquck70629.html to understand this distinction.

Comment: @Bryan Pendleton The server application uses a NetworkServerControl instance to start the server. So in this case it is an embedded java application. That accepts connections from other applications that use Derby client drivers to connect.

Comment: Cool thx. Two possible theories: (1) Your `InetAddress` variable is for `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or something similar, meaning that you told your server to only accept connections from the local machine, or (2) Your Windows Firewall is not allowing connections in to this port from outside the machine. Since it works when you run it in Netbeans I'd guess that (2) is the likely answer?

Comment: @Bryan Pendleton, I know the InetAddress is correct (a local ip forwarded from a router's real ip), mostly because it does accept remote connections when running inside Netbeans. So I would agree it should be firewall issues. I was thinking to place derby.home (and databases) in a path under the server's app distribution folder, so that I don´t mess with the firewall. But don´t know if it´s a good idea or if it would work. I wonder how Netbeans bypasses the firewall.

Comment: Maybe you (some time ago) allowed Netbeans through the firewall: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028544/windows-10-turn-windows-defender-firewall-on-or-off